# High Sierra's Finder don't index files in storage unit

Tags: macos, finder, high-sierra, filesystem, storage

Finder (macOS High Sierra) not show any files or folders that I know are there. It occurs only in with units of a storage appliance (Tiger-Box). In previous macOS versions it works fine. I can see all files and folders using Adobe Bridge but its not a good tool for that.

So. Can you guys suggest me a way to fix it? Or may be a "alternative Finder" that works.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you have tried this or not. I would suggest running the following command on Terminal to enhance the feature of SMB first.

**Speed up browsing on network shares**

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores -bool TRUE
```

**Force the Finder to gather all metadata first**

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices UseBareEnumeration -bool FALSE
```

Logout and login back from your Mac machine, and give a try to find the files from your SMB Shared Network.